# Python - Read from text file and put into a list

Tags: python

As title, I have been trying to read text from file, convert to `int` and store it in a list. My text file look like this:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

I want to read this file, put each pair of numbers into a list `m`, and store those lists in a bigger list `lis`. Here is my attempt:

```
def read_file():        
    lis = []
    m = [0,0]

    with open("data.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            m[0], m[1] = line.split(",")    # assign to list m
            m[0] = int(m[0])   # cut off '\n' and for later use
            m[1] = int(m[1])   
            lis.append(m)      # store in lis

    print lis
```

I expect the `lis` to be like this:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

But instead, it is:

```
[[5, 6], [5, 6], [5, 6]]
```

I have tried `insert` instead of `append` but it seems like that's not where it has problems. I need some help - thank you in advance!

Comment: You are reusing and overwriting the values in the very same instance `m`.

Comment: `m = [0, 0]` is the only time you create a sublist, so you've using the same one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reusing the same list `m` in each iteration of the loop, each time overwriting the values set in the previous iteration. In the end, `lis` holds many references to the same list.

Instead, assign a new value to `m` *as a whole* in the loop:

```
for line in f:
    m = [0,0]
    m[0], m[1] = line.split(",")
    m[0] = int(m[0])
    m[1] = int(m[1])   
    lis.append(m)
```

Or shorter:

```
for line in f:
    m = line.split(",")
    m[0] = int(m[0])
    m[1] = int(m[1])   
    lis.append(m)
```

Or even shorter, using map:

```
for line in f:
    m = list(map(int, line.split(",")))
    lis.append(m)
```

Or even more shorter, using a list comprehension:

```
lis = [list(map(int, line.split(","))) for line in f]
```

Comment: Thank you! Map is really clever in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
def read_file():        
    lis = []
    with open("data.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            m, n = line.split(",")    
            lis.append([int(m), int(n)])      

    print lis
```

Comment: The best code in my opinion sadly has no text for explanation... I would even suggest to step away from limiting the number of columns to 2 and use a list comprehension like `lis.append([int(i.strip()) for i in line.split(',')])`.

Answer (score 2):

In `lis` all index reference to one list `m`. If any update in `m` is takes place, `m` is update every where

[image]

Try this

```
lis.append( list(map(int,line.split(","))))
```

**Output**

> [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]

Comment: Nice illustration, but I don't think `append(m+[])` is the best way to solve the issue. IMHO, better not re-use `m` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `csv.reader` object instead which uses `,`(comma) as default field separator:

```
import csv

with open('data.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    result = [list(map(int, lst)) for lst in reader]
    print(result)
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader

Comment: While using `csv.reader` is certainly better, this sounds as if this in itself would solve the problem, but it does not. The problem is with reusing `m`, which, without any explanation, OP could do again with a `csv.reader`.